# Associação entre variáveis: base de dados

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte base de dados:

```
id Acidente    id_Vitima    Sexo_Vitima   Faixa_etaria    Gravidade_acidente
1               1             1               7              2
2               1             1               6              1
2               2             2               8              1
3               1             2               6              3
3               1             2               2              3
3               1             2               7              3
3               1             2               7              3
```

Pretendo fazer uma análise de associação entre variável `Gravidade_acidente` e a variável `Sexo_Vitima`.

A minha dúvida é que a base de dados tem `id Acidente` repetido e não sei se posso fazer fazer análise de associação com os dados nessa forma ou criar uma nova base de dados sem repetição de `id Acidente`.

Comment: Seus dados me parecem estranhos. Como você tem em um mesmo acidente, a mesma vítima com faixas etárias diferentes?

Comment: Ana, isso não me parece uma pergunta de programação, mas uma pergunta de estatística, análise de dados. Este tipo de pergunta caberia neste site aqui: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: poix é Molx tens razão