# associaçao entre variaveis

Tags: r

```
id Acidente   id_Vitima    Sexo_Vitima   Faixa_etaria       Gravidade_acidente
1              1              1               7                 1
2              1              1               3                 3
2              1              2               3                 3
3              1              2               6                 2
3              2              1               2                 2
3              3              1               7                 2
3              4              2               7                 2
```

Pretendo fazer uma análise de associação entre variável Gravidade_acidente e a variável Sexo_Vitima.

A minha dúvida é que a base de dados tem id Acidente repetido e não sei se posso fazer fazer análise de associação com os dados nessa forma ou criar uma nova base de dados sem repetição de id Acidente.

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre esta pergunta e a [outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58894/2541) que fizeste?

Comment: Parece me que ideia é ter mesmo o id Acidente repetido. Essa tabela parece ter chaves compostas. Onde o idAcidente e id_Vitima são as chaves.. Não podes ter é estes dois campos repetidos

Comment: @CesarMiguel Pode ser mais existe repetição no par 2,1. A não ser que sexo_vitima faça parte da chave, no entanto a vitima seria bissexual!

Comment: @ramaral, agora até me ri :) realmente, fazendo essa análise a vitima 1 é realmente emafrodita :P

Comment: @CesarMiguel Sim o termo correto é hermafrodita e não bissexual. ([hermafrodita](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermafrodita) e não emafrodita.)

Comment: @ramaral Devia ter consultado o google antes de escrever :/

Comment: Ana, não leve a peito os nossos comentários. De vez enquanto um pouco de humor é permitido aqui e até saudável, desde que não haja abusos!

Comment: existe erro de digitação nas variáveis id acidente e id_vitima. o correto é  par 2,1 e 2,2